# Can I make Visual Studio understand that this isn't null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

So the beginning of my controller action is

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FillOut ( Guid pid, int? sid )
    {
     // pid: partner id
     // sid (optional): survey id

    // if survey id not supplied in query string, find which survey the user should be on
        if ( sid == null )
        {
            sid = this._Db.CheckIfFinished(pid, 1) ? 2 : 1;
        }
        ViewBag.pid = pid;
        ViewBag.sid = sid;
        ViewBag.finished = this._Db.CheckIfFinished(pid,sid);
        ViewBag.survtitle = this._Db.GetSurveyTitle(sid);
        var AllAnswers = this._Db.GetAnswersByPartner(pid,sid);
```

and VS isn't happy because my methods `this._Db.CheckIfFinished(pid,sid);`, `this._Db.GetSurveyTitle(sid);` and `this._Db.GetAnswersByPartner(pid,sid)` expect the `sid` parameter to be an `int` and not an `int?`. But with how I'm using it, `sid` is guaranteed to be non-null. So is this a Visual Studio bug or is my C# technically invalid, and if it's invalid, what's the cleanest way of overcoming this issue in my particular scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug (besides it's the compiler that gets the final say).

You can either stick `.Value` everywhere you need an actual `int`, or since you need it so many times, create another non-nullable `int` variable to store the value.

Answer (score 3):

For [nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), use `.Value` to get the underlying value. So in this case, `sid.Value` will return the `int` you want.

You can also check that the variable has a value by the `HasValue` property.

Answer (score 0):

So when you've checked that `sid != null` (or `sid.HasValue`), it's safe to use `sid.Value` to get the non-nullable `int` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure then use parameter?.value instead

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FillOut ( Guid pid, int? sid )
{
 // pid: partner id
 // sid (optional): survey id

// if survey id not supplied in query string, find which survey the user should be on
    if ( !sid.HasValue )
    {
        sid = this._Db.CheckIfFinished(pid, 1) ? 2 : 1;
    }
    ViewBag.pid = pid;
    ViewBag.sid = sid;
    ViewBag.finished = this._Db.CheckIfFinished(pid,sid);
    ViewBag.survtitle = this._Db.GetSurveyTitle(sid);
    var AllAnswers = this._Db.GetAnswersByPartner(pid,sid.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But with how I'm using it, sid is guaranteed to be non-null.

It's a nullable int that isn't null, but it's still a nullable int. It's very purpose is to *possibly* be null.

You can obtain the `int` value by using it's `Value` property.

If you are **absolutely** certain that it isn't null, then as an optimisation you can call its `GetValueOrDefault()` method (the overload that doesn't take a value to use as the default). Because this method doesn't test whether the value is set to null or not it is faster. But only use this optimisation if you are **100%** sure it can't be null (e.g. just after checking exactly that, or setting it to a non-null value) because if it is null it will just return `0` rather than throwing an exception that would point out your error.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this, to get the actual int-value that is stored inside the int?-container:

```
ViewBag.pid = pid;
ViewBag.sid = sid.Value;
ViewBag.finished = this._Db.CheckIfFinished(pid, sid.Value);
ViewBag.survtitle = this._Db.GetSurveyTitle(sid.Value);
var AllAnswers = this._Db.GetAnswersByPartner(pid, sid.Value);
```